# Get categories with its related post

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

I have the following relationship built in my app between two models.

**Post.php**

```php
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category', 'category_id')->withDefault();
}
```

**Category.php**

```php
public function post()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post', 'category_id');
}
```

I want to get the data in the following format in my view:

1. Category Title 1

   - Post Title 1
   - Post Title 2
   - Post Title 3
2. Category Title 2

   - Post Title 1
   - Post Title 2
   - Post Title 3
3. Category Title

   - Post Title 1
   - Post Title 2
   - Post Title 3

**Controller**

```
$posts = Post::all();
$categories = $posts->pluck('category')->unique();
```

**View/Blade**

```php
@foreach($categories as $category)
    {{  $category->name }}
    @foreach($category as $item)
        {{  $item->post->name }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

It's not working. I am looking forward to any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Change relationship.Add foreign key in relationship.You don't have to select categories and posts in different variables.Relationship will get all datas if you properly assigned them.

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category', 'category_id','category_id');
}
public function post()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post', 'category_id','category_id');
}
$categories = Category::all();
```

In view

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
 {{$category->name}}
 @foreach($category->post as $post)
    {{$post->title}}
 @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to use plural form for your `manyToMany` method name (`posts`instead of `post`), but with current situation this code should work:

```
 @foreach($categories as $category)
      {{$category->name}}
      @foreach($category->post as $item)
        {{$item->title}}
     @endforeach
  @endforeach`
```